# how to get the value of the control loaded dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

In my page,I load some control dynamically.

**In Page**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="onchanged"></asp:DropdownList>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeholder" runat="server">
```

**In Page.aspx:**

```
public void onchanged(object sender,EventArgs e){
  Control c=loadControl('part.ascx');
  this.placeholder.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

Now,then this page is submitted,I want to get the value of the controls in the 'part.ascx',but I can not get it .

What is the problem?

Comment: Part.ascx should be displayed only when the selected item was changed in the drop down list? What conrols does part.ascx contain?

Comment: control in part.ascx:asp:TextBox